# Null Value in number field for report

Tags: reporting

I have number of items say products listed in salesforce report.
When I get aggregated result the sum of particular group is 0 when all products in that group are null. Is it possible to display null or empty value? I tried to use nullvalue, isNull, isBlank in Summary Formula field however they all seem not to work. Is it possible to display empty value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, aggregate queries will always return zero (when all values are null); null values are reserved for the [GROUP BY ROLLUP](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_rollup.htm) and [GROUP BY CUBE](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_cube.htm) aggregate query keywords.